# How to get the WPD device ID on a WPD device connect event?

Tags: wia, wpd, autoplay

In WIA (Windows Image Acquisition), we have IWiaDevMgr::RegisterEventCallbackProgram() API to register an application to receive device events. I couldn't find any similar API in WPD (Windows Portable Devices) framework.  Is there a way to get WPD device ID on a WPD device connect event?